# how to create a script that copy files to other documents folder

Tags: shell, scripting

Using a script, copy the following files to the documents folder:

- `/etc/passwd`
- `/etc/group`
- `/etc/network/interfaces`

I don't know where to start, I would appreciate it if someone could give me some advice or show me the requested script and an explanation
I'm sure it's simple but I'm new to scripts

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. I see two question you should ask yourself and do some research. 1. "*How to write a shell script*", 2. "*How to copy files*". Both simple tasks that you should find out by doing some research. I'm sure we will help you out if you show us what you tried if that is not working, but sorry, this is not a script writing service, and not a do-my-homework service.

Comment: "_if someone could [...] show me the requested script_" why should you get credit for the homework that's been done by someone else?

Comment: "_I'm new to scripts_" - that's fine. Everyone started from the beginning once. Have a go. Use https://shellcheck.net to identify the more obvious errors. Ask again when you have specific issues

Comment: Put the command(s) you would use to copy the files into a file (e.g. with the filename `myscript`).   That's a script.  Optionally make it executable with `chmod +x myscript` (if you use any bash-specific features - i.e. anything that isn't in plain old POSIX shell - you'll need to have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script), or just run it with `bash myscript`.

Comment: look at my script ! Please let me know what you think of the script .

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

cp /etc/passwd /home/user/Documents     
cp /etc/group /home/user/Documents     
cp /etc/network/interfaces /home/user/Documents

ls -l Documents
```

done

Comment: Well done for having a try - and succeeding